# C# Duplicating fields in DataGridView after reading data from multiple files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm making a program that downloads zip files from an SFTP server, unzips the files and reads the text file to display certain data in a DataGridView but for some reason its duplicating the values after 10-15 files

Result:

[image: Result]

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridView dexRead;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this is the Designer.cs code...
        dexRead = new DataGridView();
        ((ISupportInitialize)(this.dexRead)).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();

        dexRead.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dexRead.Location = new Point(12, 12);
        dexRead.Name = "dexRead";
        dexRead.Size = new Size(606, 400);
        dexRead.TabIndex = 0;

        AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        ClientSize = new Size(630, 434);
        Controls.Add(dexRead);
        Name = "Form1";
        Text = "Form1";
        ((ISupportInitialize)(this.dexRead)).EndInit();
        ResumeLayout(false);

        string zipTemp = (@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\zipTemp\");
        string machineCashCount = ("");
        string hostIP = ("0.0.0.0");
        string userName = ("un");
        string passWord = ("pw");
        string remotePath = (@"/home/dex/RESPONSE/PROCESSED");
        string localPath = (@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\PROCESSED\");


        IList<Machine> machines = new BindingList<Machine>();
        dexRead.DataSource = machines;

        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = hostIP,
            UserName = userName,
            Password = passWord,
            PortNumber = 22,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 96:48:96:52:8c:e7:de:c6:e1:00:08:7e:db:ad:e4:06"

        };

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            session.GetFiles(remotePath, @"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\").Check();
        }

        DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\PROCESSED\");
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.zip"))
        {
            fileNames.Add(fileInfo.Name);
        }

        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            string zipFilePath = localPath + fileName;
            string[] timeDate = fileName.Split('_');
            string Date = timeDate[1];
            string Time = timeDate[2];
            string[] tme = Time.Split('.');
            string tm = tme[0];
            string dateTime = Date + tm;

            DateTime dTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MMddyyyyHHmmss",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string daTime = dTime.ToString();

            using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipFilePath))
            {
                var selection = (from e in zip1.Entries
                                 where (e.FileName).StartsWith("01e")
                                 select e);

                Directory.CreateDirectory(zipTemp);

                foreach (var e in selection)
                {
                    e.Extract(zipTemp, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }

            DirectoryInfo dexDirect = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\zipTemp\");
            List<string> dexName = new List<string>();
            List<string> dexDate = new List<string>();

            foreach (FileInfo dexInfo in dexDirect.GetFiles("*.dex"))
            {
                dexName.Add(dexInfo.Name);
            }

            foreach (string dexNames in dexName)
            {
                string dexFilePath = zipTemp + dexNames;

                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dexFilePath);

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    machineCashCount = Array.Find(lines,
                element => element.StartsWith("VA1", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                }

                string[] MCC1 = machineCashCount.Split('*');
                string[] nm = dexNames.Split('.');
                

                int nam = int.Parse(nm[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                Console.WriteLine((nam + (":") + "Total cash count: ") + MCC1[1]);
                Console.WriteLine((nam + (":") + "Number of paid vends: ") + MCC1[2]);


                Machine m = new Machine();

                m.MacNum = nam;
                m.CashCount = MCC1[1];
                m.VendCount = MCC1[2];
                m.Date_and_Time = daTime;
                machines.Add(m);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\zipTemp"), File.Delete);
        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\PROCESSED"), File.Delete);
    }
}
class Machine
{
    public int MacNum { get; set; }
    public string CashCount { get; set; }
    public string VendCount { get; set; }
    public string Date_and_Time { get; set; }
}
```

}

I'm kinda new to programming in C# and I would really appreciate any help I can get, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
    IList<Machine> machines = new BindingList<Machine>();
    dexRead.DataSource = machines;
```

to:

```
    var machines = new List<Machine>();
```

Add this line at the end of the method:

```
    dexRead.DataSource = new BindingList<Machine>(machines.Distinct().ToList());
```

Also add necessary equality operator to your Machine class. http://www.aaronstannard.com/overriding-equality-in-dotnet/ shows you how to do this.

Comment: Did that help Mark?